# External SSD/HDD slowed down

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, storage

I have an SSD and HDD in an external USB 3.0 dock. Just a few days I had 300~ Mb/sec  read/ write speed on the SSD and 65~ Mb/sec on the HDD. Now, the SSD speed dropped  to 40 and HDD went down to 10.

I tried disabling the USB device, uninstalling the device/driver, and trying another port; none of those worked, so as my last hope I decided to format the SSD and its speed went back up... for a while. Now it is back at low speed.

How may I troubleshoot the cause of this problem?

Comment: @K7AAY they are docked

Comment: What is the make and model of the dock?